# I can't use the keyboard to enter F8 to continue Windows XP installation

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine

I have installed Virtual Box on my iMac Intel Processor and am trying to install Windows XP as the guest. It goes as far as the window that says 
WindowsXP Virtual Box[Running]
F8=I agree ESC=I do not agree PAGE UP=Previous Page

I have the mouse in Virtual Machine Capture but the keyboard does not respond. Some of the keys work but not F8 (Page Up works so why doesn't F8?) How do I answer the Windows XP Licensing Agreement if I can't enter F8?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The F# keys on the mac are mapped to alternate functions like play|pause.  Try holding down Function and pressing F8 to get the "default" behavior.

Comment: Good thing I have an extra Microsoft keyboard. The Mac keyboard doesn't have the Function key, at least I can't see it! For future reference, does the Mac keyboard have a dedicated Function key?

Comment: Hah!Just found it directly below the F13 key! Isn't Google great! And thanks Chris for your help!